# сравнение строки с массивом charов

Tags: .net, строки, char

Доброй ночи не могу разобратся как сделать по символьную проверку строки с массивом charов?

```
class Program
{
    public static string getStr(char[] s)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            ret += s[i];
        return ret;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] s2 = new char[] { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '=', ':', ';', '"', '?', '/', '.', ',', '<', '>', '!', '№', '|' };
        if (string.Compare(s1, getStr(s2)) == 0)

            Console.WriteLine("==");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("!=");


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Пример приведите, а то неясно, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] s2 = new char[] { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '=', ':', ';', '"', '?', '/', '.', ',', '<', '>', '!', '№', '|' };

        bool areEqual = false;
        //Если длина неодинакова - уже неодинаковые нет смысла сравнивать по символам
        areEqual = s1.Length == s2.Count();

        //конвертируем строку в массив char
        char[] charArrayFromString = s1.ToCharArray();

        if (areEqual)
        {
            areEqual = charArrayFromString.SequenceEqual(s2);
        }

        if (areEqual)
            Console.WriteLine("==");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("!=");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнивай с

```
string s3 = new string(s2);
```